# Callback for $.post cannot access this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a beginner in JavaScript/jQuery, etc. and I'm facing a little problem maybe you could help me to solve. I have an object prototype name **Page** and in it there is an array and a function that do an AJAX POST and process the answer. The code looks like this:

```
function Page( url ){
    this.url = url;
    this.elarr = [];

    this.addElem = function( elem ){
        this.elarr.push( elem );
    }

    this.job = function(){
        $.post( this.url,
            {
                // some data here...
            },
            function( data, status ){
                var decodedData = JSON.parse( data );
                this.elarr[0].value = decodedData.value; // Error: elarr is not defined
            });
    }
};
```

I do something like: `var page = new Page( 'page.php' ); page.addElem( new Elem );` where `Elem` is a prototype with `.value`.

The php code on server side answers correctly to the POST request. By using Chrome development tools, I can step the JavaScript code and the decoded Json answer is correct. The problem arises when it tries to access `this.elarr[0]` (yes, in page1, elarr[0] exists!) For example, if I replace the bogus line by the hardcoded `page1.elarr[0].value = decodedData.value;` it works perfectly.

I know that the callback function is asynchronous and maybe the **this** is meaningless in it (it seems to be!) Also I read about "closures" but I'm not sure if it is the solution to my problem. I'm pretty sure it is simple but I cannot figure the solution with my limited knowledge. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the ajax callback method `this` refers to the jqXHR setting object, in this case you can use a custom context using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [$.proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
function Page(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.elarr = [];

    this.addElem = function (elem) {
        this.elarr.push(elem);
    }

    this.job = function () {
        $.post(this.url, {
            // some data here...
        }, (function (data, status) {
            var decodedData = JSON.parse(data);
            this.elarr[0].value = decodedData.value; // Error: elarr is not defined
        }).bind(this));
    }
};
```

---

Another option is to use a closure variable

```
function Page(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.elarr = [];

    this.addElem = function (elem) {
        this.elarr.push(elem);
    }

    var self = this; //closure variable
    this.job = function () {
        $.post(this.url, {
            // some data here...
        }, function (data, status) {
            var decodedData = JSON.parse(data);
            self.elarr[0].value = decodedData.value; // Error: elarr is not defined
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution works fine, the `self` is a good way to proceed for me. Now I understand a little more "closures".

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `that` to handle different `this` closures such as:

```
function Page( url ){

    var that = this;
    that.url = url;
    that.elarr = [];

    that.addElem = function( elem ){
        this.elarr.push( elem );
    }

    that.job = function(){
        $.post( this.url,
            {
                // some data here...
            },
            function( data, status ){
                var decodedData = JSON.parse( data );
                that.elarr[0].value = decodedData.value; // Error: elarr is not defined        
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: I used self but the solution is the same. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, just define the self or that property at the top and add it to your variables and functions, allows you to call them more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `context` option of `$.ajaxSettings` object

```
function Page( url ){
        this.url = url;
        this.elarr = [];

        this.addElem = function( elem ){
            this.elarr.push( elem );
        }

        this.job = function(){
            $.ajax( {
                url:this.url,
                // some data here...
                data:{},
                // set `context`
                context:this,
                type:"POST"
                })
                .then(function( data, status ){
                    var decodedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    this.elarr[0].value = decodedData.value; // Error: elarr is not defined
                });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about context option. I'll give it a try. Thanks.